# select spcefique texte inside div

Tags: jquery, selector

i'm trying to build html website, i want to select the text inside a div

```
<div class="periodic">
 <div class="periodic-row">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="at_num">102</div>
      <div class="symbol">No</div>
      <div class="at_details">nobelium<br />[259.10]</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="at_num">103</div>
      <div class="symbol">Lr</div>
      <div class="at_details">lawrencium<br />[262.11]</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have like 103 `<div class="element">` and I want when I click on random div div I could select a text in this case nobelium or lawrencium....

I tried this jquery selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".periodic").click(function(){
      var text = $(this).text();
      alert(text)
    });
  })
</script>
```

that alert all 103 text of div but i only want the text inside div that i clicked

after some research i'm trying this code and it look better

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".periodic").find("div").click(function(event){
         event.stopPropagation();
      var text = $(this).text();
      alert(text)
    });
    });
```

but i still need to select only last text exemple lawrencium

Answer (score -1):

```
     <div id="testText">
     test
     </div>

      var mb = $('#testText').text();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help others understand it better. Code only answers are considered impolite.